# Как передаются данные в параметры функций и как избежать потери данных на пути

Tags: c, функции, указатели, структуры

Давно мучился с функцией, удаляющей элемент в односвязном списке подобного рода:

```
typedef struct List* plist;

typedef struct List {
    int val;
    plist next;
} List;
```

Обнаружил странную вещь, от которой руки опускаются. Вот функция и, собственно, тестовый main (этот код рабочий):

```
void delete(plist* this) {
    plist tmp = (*this)->next;
    free(*this);
    *this = tmp;
}

int main() {
    int val;
    plist list = NULL;

    for (val = 1; val < 6; val++) {
        list = addpage(list, val);      //создание элемента в конце списка, рекурсивная, с ней проблем нет
    }
    plist last = list;                  /*(не пишу всего, чтобы не загромождать)*/

    while (last->next)
        last = last->next;

    delete(&list->next->next);

    printlist(list);                    //рекурсивная, печатает список, пока не уткнётся в NULL

    return 0;
}
```

Расширяя код, я увеличил путь аргумента ("list->n.->n."), добавив в него (в путь) ещё пару функций, после чего тот же delete стал выдавать другие значения - то он, освобождая память (забивая поле "value" мусором), сам элемент из списка не убирал, то (конкретно в том виде кода, что приведён ниже) зацикливал список. Вот код с расширенным путём аргумента:

```
void change(plist* this) {
    plist tmp = (*this)->next;
    free(*this);
    *this = tmp;
}
void through2(plist this) {
    change(&this);
}
void through1(plist this) {
    through2(this);
}

int main() {
    
    /***тот же код***/

    through1(list->next->next);

    printlist(list);

    return 0;
}
```

Так вот вопрос: что ту происходит и как подобного можно избежать? Если у меня есть ошибки в коде - я буду рад и благодарен, если вы на них укажите. Функции addpage() и printlist() проверены мною и временем, потому не вижу смысла лишний раз вам глаза портить. Жду любой помощи - уже несколько месяцев бегаю вокруг списков, ломая голову.

p.s.: после пары часов решил сбросить для демонстрации кусочек скрина с маркированным кодом:

```
void change(plist* this) {
    plist tmp = (*this)->next;
    free(*this);
    *this = tmp;
    printf("\nchange: %p", *this);
}
void through2(plist this) {
    printf("\n2: %p", this);
    change(&this);
    printf("\n2: %p", this);
}
void through1(plist this) {
    printf("\n1: %p", this);
    through2(this);
    printf("\n1: %p", this);
}
```

(это всё те же, только с обеих сторон от передач стоят выводы адресов this'а - по одному до преобразования и по одному после).

[image: то, что выводится. Как видно, through1 остался со старым значением]

Я подозреваю, что здесь необходим volatile, но то ли я как-то неправильно его использую, то ли не решает это проблему. Volatile использовал на объявлении list - объекта головы структуры, а также пробовал на this в through1.

Comment: Здесь не нужен никакой `volatile`, надо просто нарисовать картинку и посмотреть, куда и что указывает после вашего т.н. "удаления"... Спойлер: куда указывает `next` узла *перед* удаляемым до и после удаления? А куда должен?

Comment: @Harry, спасибо за отзыв, но я бы поэксплуатировал ваше внимание ещё немного. Удаление из предыдущего - классическая практика, но я часто встречал подобные утверждения: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12914917/using-pointers-to-remove-item-from-singly-linked-list. Как и говорил, такой подход срабатывает без нагромождения функциями (это и есть действие пресловутой оптимизации?). Думаю, стоило действительно начать именно с этого - моя вина. Согласитесь: для чайника такой подход выглядит более привлекательным своей лаконичностью. Имеет ли он место быть в реальности, так сказать?

Comment: p.s.: поверьте, я порядочно порвал тетрадь, чтобы придти к понимаю принципа. Так в один момент я решил, что понял) Я к тому, что не стоит думать, будто вопрошающий сам ответов не ищет

Comment: функция `void through1(plist this)` меняет локальную переменную `this`. И с наружи не видно, что указатель изменился. Делайте как в `delete(plist* this)`, передавайте указатель на указатель `void through1(plist * thisp)`

Comment: @AlexGlebe , пришёл домой, проверил - действительно помогло. Спасибо большое! Единственное, не могли бы дать что-нибудь для дальнейшего "гуглирования"? Не хотелось бы снова встревать с подобным. Но я вам правда благодарен